# flink kafka connector v1.13 how to commit?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I see that's what the official document says：

The way to configure offset commit behaviour is different, depending on whether checkpointing is enabled for the job.

Checkpointing disabled: if checkpointing is disabled, the Flink Kafka Consumer relies on the automatic periodic offset committing capability of the internally used Kafka clients. Therefore, to disable or enable offset committing, simply set the enable.auto.commit / auto.commit.interval.ms keys to appropriate values in the provided Properties configuration.

Checkpointing enabled: if checkpointing is enabled, the Flink Kafka Consumer will commit the offsets stored in the checkpointed states when the checkpoints are completed. This ensures that the committed offsets in Kafka brokers is consistent with the offsets in the checkpointed states. Users can choose to disable or enable offset committing by calling the setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints(boolean) method on the consumer (by default, the behaviour is true). Note that in this scenario, the automatic periodic offset committing settings in Properties is completely ignored.

i want to know when Checkpointing disabled，but "enable.auto.commit" is "false", how to commit offset in kafka? I just want to submit manually, not automatically